# Why does new String * 1 return 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, why is:

```
new String * 1
<- 0
```

What exactly makes it return `0`, and why is the following equal to `NaN`?

```
function Foo() { this.bar = 0; }
new Foo * 5;
<- NaN
```

Comment: What did you expect it to be if not `0`? Also `"" * 1` or `{valueOf() { return 0; }} * 1}` have the same result.

Comment: Or: Try `Number("")`, `Number(new String)` and `Number(new Foo)`

Comment: @Bergi `NaN` perhaps? I'm asking _why_. I understand that those return `0`, but that doesn't help explain it.

Comment: Section [7.1.3.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-mv-s) of the ECMA 6.0 specification requires that the mathematical value of `StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty]` is 0.

Comment: Similarly in ECMA 5.1 Section [9.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1) : A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0

Comment: @CharlieS: That's what I already linked above. However, that details only *how* it works not *why*.

Comment: @Bergi I can see where you're coming from, however debating why it was specified like that seems a bit fruitless. For most of us the *why* ends when we see the ratified specification this is typically considered the reason *why* not the how, the latter being the implementation logic that many js developers don't delve into.

Comment: @DavidBarker: I see. So [most of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+title%3Awhy) could be answered with a simple "*Because the spec says so.*"?

Comment: @Bergi haha, no I don't, which is why I didn't answer this question with a statement that was comment worthy at best ;-) however it does go, **in this instance** ,a long way to a reason for the behaviour enquired about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use arithmetic operators like `*`, JavaScript will try to convert the type to a number. An empty string becomes `0`.

If you have, for example:

```
new String("foo") * 1
```

You will notice it returns `NaN` because the conversion to a number could not be completed. That's what happens in your second situation.

Answer (score 6):

When you use arithmetic operators, the operands will be converted to numbers first.

In the first case, on your left hand side expression you have an empty string. Empty strings will become 0, when converted to a number, as per this [section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) in the specification.

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

Since `new String` is just a string object with zero characters, it is empty and that is why your first expression is evaluated to zero (`0 * 1`).

---

In the second case, `new Foo` returns an object that cannot be converted to a number. If an object cannot be converted to a number, then `NaN` will be returned. Quoting the same section on the spec,

> If the grammar cannot interpret the String as an expansion of StringNumericLiteral, then the result of ToNumber is NaN.

That is why the result is `NaN` here (`NaN * 5`).

---

You can check these things yourselves.

```
console.log(+(new String()));
// 0
console.log(+{});
// NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

`new String` returns a `String` object, which has a [primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) of `""`

`""` parsed as a number is `0`.

So when you do `new String * 1`, it is as if you did `0 * 1`.

Your `Foo` object does not specify any kind of primitive value, so it cannot work that out for you and you get `NaN`

If you write `new String` in your console, you should see the primitive value in the result